# Dangers to the Vanilla Nethacker in SLASH'EM

Tags: nethack, slashem

I've been playing Nethack for a little while, and I'd like to try SLASH'EM.  I understand there is a lot of new stuff in SLASH'EM - magic, items, monsters, classes, etc.  I've also heard that it's considerably harder!

What I'm wondering is what unexpected dangers exist in SLASH'EM, but not Nethack - stuff that is different in a way that's liable to kill me without warning.  (Also, if there are any new advantages I can abuse - a super-Elbereth or something - that'd be nice to know about too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all you need to know is right here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~eva/slashem/index.html

There are many links on that page that will give you almost all the information you're looking for. I'd give it a thorough read before you begin playing SLASH'EM.

Other than that, there really isn't anything else you need to know that you don't already know. No super-Elbereth, and nothing that's liable of killing you outside of general NetHack shenanigans.

If you use the NetHack Wiki remember that some of the information on the Wiki may not be consistent with SLASH'EM.

Good luck!

PS: SLASH'EM isn't more difficult than vanilla NetHack; it's merely a different flavor.